# can i get back up of photos. I've lost my android phone

Tags: backup

i've lost my phone 2 days back in which my Google account was registered however i'm not able to find those pictures & videos now in my google account. I'm not sure if i had clicked on back up photos link or not. Is there any way i can get those photos. Plz help as i've so many memories captured in that phone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used Google to backup your photos, any backed up content would appear on [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com).

In addition, try using [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?hl=en_GB&u=0) to locate your phone, if possible. Or at least lock it.